# jQuery 1.2.6 caching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing quite a bit of DOM manipulation in my app, adding new nodes, and I've found that the children() function can get out of sync. I've got a tbody element with two rows, I use the children() function on this to do some manipulation with these rows. I then add two more rows to the tbody, when I use the children function again to do more manipulation I only get back the original two rows, not these plus the two rows I've just added. I'm doing a new call to children every time, not relying on any variable to auto-update. Is there any way to clear jQuery's cache - I've noticed problems like this a few times with selectors and got around it by selecting further up the DOM tree then navigating back down (i.e. don't select the tbody with a jQuery CSS selector, select the table then do table.tBodies[0].rows), but that won't work in this case.

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Why don't you update to the newest version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The children() function doesn't get out of sync. You have to execute that again if you changed the DOM. On modifying you can have a callback that remakes your array of matched elements. This is not a cache mechanism, is like JavaScript works: linear. Ajax calls are sometimes cached but doesn't seem the case here.

**Recommendation**
Always use the latest version of jQuery: 1.3.2 now.

**Update**. So this is your code:

```
function removeGroup() { 
    var groupNodes = [ $('#row1')[0], $('#row2') ];  // is this correct? 
    var parent = groupNodes[0].parentNode; 
    if ( $(parent).children().length > 2) { 
        parent.removeChild(groupNodes[0]); // why not use dirrectly $('#row1')[0].remove();?
        parent.removeChild(groupNodes[1]); // same here
    } else { 
        alert("Can't delete last group"); 
    } 
}
```

This code has nothing to do with caching and most of it doenst even pass through jQuery.
Better explain what you want to do and will do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Unfortunately, the version of jQuery is forced onto me, I'd update if I could!

There is definitely some sort of caching going on, because I am calling $(myNode).children every time, not relying on some old value, but $(myNode).children returns two tr elements whereas $(myNode).rows returns four tr elements. I've given up with the jQuery way for now and just gone to using the rows collection.

Comment: sorry - that's myNode.rows, not $(myNode).rows!

Comment: can we see a simplified example?

Comment: Sure: 
function removeGroup() {
var groupNodes = [ $('#row1')[0], $('#row2') ];
var parent = groupNodes[0].parentNode;

if ($(parent).children().length > 2) {
 parent.removeChild(groupNodes[0]);
 parent.removeChild(groupNodes[1]);
} else {
 alert("Can't delete last group");
}
}
This function gets called when someone clicks a button, but the children() function doesn't seem to reflect the latest version of the DOM tree

Comment: ah, forgot it strips out carriage returns here - can you make that out?

Comment: it will be a good idea to read the FAQ to see how you can format code, until I take a look :)

Comment: Most of it doesn't pass through jQuery, you're right. The 'caching' I was referring to, however, is on the fourth line: `if ( $(parent).children().length > 2) {`. On repeated calls to the function, this always returns the same number, never updating. if I use `$(parent).rows.length` it gives me the correct number. Therefore jquery must be caching the value somehow...

Comment: try using $('selector').size() function to get the number of elements, but it should be the same as length.  maybe you don't add the element to the dom correctly? try to see what value $(parent).children().length has. This values are not cached. There is something else that you do wrong. Show me the part of code where you add an element.

Comment: To add to the dom, I create a document fragment (document.createDocumentFragment), build up my dom tree (mostly via doing a clone(true) on some existing nodes, then individualising id values), then do parent.appendChild(docFragment).

Comment: if using jQuery ... use $(parent).append(), or prepend() functions. this will be sure its detected correctly/